# Extract a substring between two characters in R (REGEX)

Tags: r, regex

I am having trouble using regular expressions to extract a longitude and latitude from a string. The string is this:

```
[1] "\"42.352800\" data-longitude=\"-71.187500\" \"22\"></div>"
```

I want to be able to get both the first number "42.352800" and the second number "-71.187500" separately as two variables. Because I'll be doing this on a bunch of entries, I need to make sure that it can get these numbers whether they are positive or negative.

I figured I should be using a regular expression to say basically:

latitude <- from " to " (to get the first number)

and then something similar to get the longitude.

Any ideas here? I am relatively new to regex.

Comment: It looks as if you are scraping HTML (based on the `</div>`). It might be better to look at the data source itself instead of regex, in case it is more parseable. (Regex should not always be your first attempt at accessing data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @r2evans that if you are scraping this information from a webpage it would be much simpler to get data using `rvest` for example.

To answer your question, you can use `str_match` to get first two numbers.

```
string <- "\"42.352800\" data-longitude=\"-71.187500\" \"22\"></div>"

stringr::str_match(string, '(\\d+\\.\\d+).*?(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)')[, -1]
#[1] "42.352800"  "-71.187500"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Works like a charm. Could you explain to me a little more as to what is going on with this expression? Would this still work if the first number were negative? Also, good point on rvest. The reason I am not using it is because the location data is not something you can grab using rvest. It's hidden underneath other things in the web page and I was unable to extract it using rvest.

Comment: No, this will not work if first number is negative, You need to include the same regex as the second number in that case `(-?\\d+\\.\\d+).*?(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)` where `-?` means an optional negative sign which may or may not occur.